# Send compressed images from server and uncompress them in client

Tags: image, webserver, compression, android-volley, http-compression

I'm developing a project using CakePHP 3 for server side and Android for client side. In this project I have to send a lot of images of products  from the server to the app. When the app requests the images of a product, the server searches in the database for the urls of the images and send them to the app through a json response. Then, in the app I load the images using NetworkImageView from Volley library.

This process works, but the images are heavy in size, so it consumes a lot of data if you use mobile network like 4g. I can't to lose image quality, so I can't treat the images too much.

What I was thinking was to compress (somehow) the images in server side, send the array of bytes through json and uncompress them in the app, so I could minimize data consumption.

I coudn't find any info for what I described above and I'm not sure if this is the right aproach. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I was thinking was to compress (somehow) the images in server side, send the array of bytes through json and uncompress them in the app, so I could minimize data consumption.

JSON will *increase* and not lower the amount of data that needs to be send for obvious reasons. It's an envelope in your use case and the way JSON works it will add *more* data. Check the JSON spec.

You want to enable gzip compression on your Webserver ([Nginx here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/)), check Google for that or superuser.com for more details.

But this won't make a dramatic difference either for mobile use when you send a 20mpx image. I would send *small* images and only send a lager version when needed, when the user zooms in. Guess that's doable.